# CSS multiple tables in same page with different IDs

Tags: css

We have two different tables in the same page. different IDs required for another purpose. So we created multiple CSS table elements in the Style . But only the first one is working. If i keep the customers design on top it will be applied , but only one at a time.

```css
#salescss {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

#salescss td, #salescss th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}

#salescss tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#salescss tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#salescss th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #357EC7;
    color: white;
body {font-family: Arial;}


 #customers {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

#customers td, #customers th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#customers th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #357EC7;
    color: white;
body {font-family: Arial;}
```

Comment: If you don't share your relevant HTML we can't offer any suggestions as regards your CSS selectors.

Comment: It worked. Answer by Nandita resolved. Sorry for not posting the HTML.

Comment: I am voting to close this quesition because it was caused by a simple typo error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a missing `}` after `#salescss th {` and `#customers th {`

```
#salescss {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}    
#salescss td, #salescss th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}

#salescss tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#salescss tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#salescss th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #357EC7;
    color: white;
    }
body {font-family: Arial;}


 #customers {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

#customers td, #customers th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#customers th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #357EC7;
    color: white;
    }
body {font-family: Arial;}
```

Comment: please avoid answering questions when it's a simple typo error ... there is a flag for this purpose as those questions/answers will not be useful for futur readers and will be noises in the site.

Comment: thanks @TemaniAfif :) I didnt realise that. will avoid in future. what should i do now? Should i delete the answer and post it as a comment?

Comment: you can no more delete your answer since it's accepted but you can still cast a close vote to the question so it get closed and then later deleted

Comment: Ok  will do that. Thanks :)